# File upload optional on PHP form submit

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which has an option to upload a file too, however, currently, the form throws error 4 if there is no file uploaded. I want to make the file upload optional and not mandatory. 
What do I have to change on the code below to achieve that? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
}else{
    $file=$_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'];
    $image = $_FILES["documents"] ["name"];
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['documents']['name']);
    $size = $_FILES["documents"] ["size"];
    $error = $_FILES["documents"] ["error"];
    if ($error > 0){
        die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
    }else{
        if($size > 10000000) //conditions for the file
        {
            die("Format is not allowed or file size is too big!");
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["documents"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["documents"]["name"]);          
            $documents=$_FILES["documents"]["name"];
            $emp_id= $_POST['emp_id'];
            $name= $_POST['name'];
            $title= $_POST['title'];
            $department= $_POST['department'];
            $leavetype= $_POST['leavetype'];
            $startdate= $_POST['startdate'];
            $enddate= $_POST['enddate'];
            $comments= $_POST['comments'];
            $status= $_POST['status'];
            $user= $_POST['user'];
            mysql_query("insert into medical (emp_id, name, title, department, leavetype, startdate, enddate, comments, documents, status, user) 
                         values('$emp_id', '$name','$title', '$department', '$leavetype', '$startdate', '$enddate', '$comments', '$documents', '$status', '$user')") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
}
?>
```

---

Here is the form:

```
 <form method="post" action="adds.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table class="table1">
                        <tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Employee ID</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="emp_id" placeholder="Employee Number" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Full name</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Job Title</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Job Title"  /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Department</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="department" placeholder="Department"  /></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Type of Leave:</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><select name="leavetype" >
                                    <option value="Medical Leave">Medical Leave</option>
                                    <option value="Personal Leave">Personal Leave</option>
                                    <option value="Recruitment fairs/Interviews">Recruitment fairs/Interviews</option>
                                    <option value="Paternity Leave">Paternity Leave</option>
                                    <option value="Maternity Leave">Maternity Leave</option>
                                    <option value="Compassionate Leave">Compassionate Leave</option>
                                    <option value="Marriage Leave">Marriage Leave</option>
                                    <option value="Bereavement Leave">Bereavement Leave</option>
                                    <option value="Professional Development">Professional Development</option>
                                </select></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Start Date:</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate" placeholder="0000-00-00"/></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">End Date:</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate" placeholder="0000-00-00"/></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Additional Notes:</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="comments" name="comments"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Supporting Documents</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="file" name="documents" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Status</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="status" name="status" value="Pending" readonly></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <td><label style="color:#3a87ad; font-size:18px;">Signature:</label></td>
                            <td width="30"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="<?php echo strtoupper(substr($_SERVER["AUTH_USER"], 4));?>" readonly></td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>


    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></div></form>
```

Comment: Pleassse stop using `mysql_` functions. This code shouldn't be used in new development. It has been deprecated for at least 5 years, and removed in the most recent PHP versions. It allows SQL injectable code, which you've written here. To make it non contigent on the file close the conditional prior to the query, add an `else` so you set default values, then execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

use this minimum line of code

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $emp_id= $_POST['emp_id'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $title= $_POST['title'];
    $department= $_POST['department'];
    $leavetype= $_POST['leavetype'];
    $startdate= $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate= $_POST['enddate'];
    $comments= $_POST['comments'];
    $status= $_POST['status'];
    $user= $_POST['user'];
    $document = "";
//if file is empty directly insert in table 
    if (isset($_FILES['documents']) && is_array($_FILES['documents']) && count($_FILES['documents']) > 0) {
        $file=$_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'];
        $image = $_FILES["documents"] ["name"];
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['documents']['name']);
        $size = $_FILES["documents"] ["size"];
        $error = $_FILES["documents"] ["error"];
        if ($error > 0){
            die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
            exit;
        }else{
            if($size > 10000000) //conditions for the file
            {
                die("Format is not allowed or file size is too big!");
                exit;
            }else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["documents"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["documents"]["name"]);          
                $documents=$_FILES["documents"]["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    mysql_query("insert into medical (emp_id, name, title, department,leavetype, startdate, enddate, comments,status, user) values('$emp_id', '$name','$title', '$department', '$leavetype', '$startdate', '$enddate', '$comments','$status', '$user')") or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location:index.php');
?>
```